# Ubuntu Tweak not working properly in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-tweak

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.1

After upgrading Ubuntu-Tweak-Tool as not working as expected.

The tweak setting is not displaying anything.

Screenshot is as:
[image: Tweaks]

There in option showing under Appearance, Startup, Desktop, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Remove Old Ubuntu Tweak using following command in terminal ( Ctrl+Alt+T) .

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-tweak
```

Download new Ubuntu Tweak debian package for trusty (current it's ubuntu-tweak_0.8.7-1~trusty2_all.deb )  from http://ubuntu-tweak.com/.

Type following command in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i Downloads/ubuntu-tweak_0.8.7-1~trusty2_all.deb
```